# How to share Newman htmlextra report?

Tags: postman, newman

This may be a basic question but I cannot figure out the answer.  I have a simple postman collection that is run through newman

`newman run testPostman.json -r htmlextra`

That generates a nice dynamic HTML report of the test run.

How can I then share that with someone else?  i.e. via email.   The HTML report is just created through a local URL and I can't figure out how to save it so it stays in its dynamic state.  Right clicking and Save As `.html` saves the file, but you lose the ability to click around in it.

I realize that I can change the export path so it saves to some shared drive somewhere, but aside from that is there any other way?

Comment: If there's something that's confusing or doesn't make sense - feel free to raise an issue on the reporters GH repo and I can provide more information. https://github.com/DannyDainton/newman-reporter-htmlextra

Comment: https://softans.com/apis-automation-via-newman-and-generate-html-reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been already saved to `newman/` in the current working directory, no need to 'Save As' one more time. You can zip it and send via email.

If you want to change the location of generated report, check [this](https://github.com/DannyDainton/newman-reporter-htmlextra#with-newman-cli).

Comment: ok, so zipping it and sending it would keep the dynamic state in tact.  Got it, thats what I was getting at.  Probably easier just to change to a central location for others to view.  Thanks